# Will my Apple MacBook Air run Counter-Strike: Global Offensive?

Tags: macbook-pro

The specs are:

- OS X Yosemite (10.10)
- MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2011)
- Processor: 1.7 GHz Intel Core i5
- Memory: 4 GB 133 MHz DDR3
- Video Card: Intel HD Graphics 3000 384 MB

I can't find any good websites, can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

When you are purchasing software, you need to review the System Requirements ***before*** making the purchase to ensure that it works with your hardware.

Per the [Steam Store](http://store.steampowered.com/app/730/) the Mac OS X Requirements are as follows:

[image]

However, if you are still not sure, you should direct your question to the Steam folks.

Comment: The issue is is the video card better than the two given? and note the specs are not from Steam but the publishers

Comment: Thank you very much for your respond i'm going to try it out!

Answer (score 0):

Being a well-optimized, OpenGL game, I am pretty certain it will run pretty fine on you Mac (you might need to turn some of the video settings down). But either way, you can always get a refund for the game:

> You can request a refund for nearly any purchase on Steam—for any reason. Maybe your PC doesn't meet the hardware requirements; maybe you bought a game by mistake; maybe you played the title for an hour and just didn't like it.

(from the [Steam website](http://store.steampowered.com))

I really recommend you read more about Steam Refunds [here](http://store.steampowered.com/steam_refunds/), and then buy the game. It's a really awesome, EXTREMELY competitive game (and I mean, 120-tick rate type of competitive) with a HUGE and very... interesting community. Unless you are Russian, then you might want to re-consider it. #RussianStrikeSilverOffensive :P

Comment: Thank you very much for your respond i'm going to try it out!